# EFCore: Is it possible to track changes made to the properties of a newly created and added to the DbContext entry? I'mNOT asking for EntryState.Added

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, change-tracking

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; } 

    public Person()
    {
        Id = 0;
        LastName = String.Empty;
        FirstName = String.Empty;
        DOB = DateTime.Now;
    }
}



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var v = new Person(){
                    LastName = "LLLLL";
                    FirstName = "FFFFF";
                    DOB = DateTime.Now;
                };

    _dbContext.Add(v);




    // now let's say that the user changes the v.LastName to ...
    v.LastName = "QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ";

    /* now I would expect _dbContext to be already aware of changes 
       made to the v.LastName property or at least to have passed the initial
       values of the v entity to the OriginalValues of the added entry
       and EFCore to providing me with a method to informing me, 
       whenever I asked so,
       if some property values in the entity, being tracked, have been changed!!
    */


   //so whenever I type
   var changesMadeSoFar = HelloLovelyEFCore_DoWeHaveAnyChangesToThePropertiesOfThisLovelyEntryMadeSoFar(EntityEntry v);

  // Unfortunatelly I can't find a way to be inormed of any changes in the properties
  // of the entry being tracked!! Unless I am missing something... (which is very possible)

  //  Even the following fails to provide me information of property changes
      made to a NEWLY created entity NOT a loaded for the DB ones.....

    EntityEntry<TFlatVisit> entry = _dbContext.Entry(v);
    entry.DetectChanges();
    var modified = entry.Members.Where(m => m.IsModified).ToList();
    var modified2 = entry.Properties.Where(m => m.CurrentValue != m.OriginalValue).ToList();
    var modified3 = entry.Properties.Where(m => m.CurrentValue == m.OriginalValue).ToList();

    var modified4 = entry.Properties
        .Where(prop => prop.IsModified)
        .Select(prop => new
        {
            Property = prop.Metadata,
            Value = prop.CurrentValue,
            Name = prop.Metadata.Name,
            PrevValue = prop.OriginalValue
        }).ToList();

 
    if (_dbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges())
    {
        _dbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        Debug.WriteLine(_dbContext.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
    }// the latter results into _dbContext has changed and the state of entry v is set to Added (we all know that)

}
```

PS: I am not asking to get if the entry has changed!! The entry state is changed to Added. We all know that!! I am specifically asking for a way to know if some or any of the entry's properties have changed. And I would like to get this info via EFCore!! Not via INotifyPropertyChanged and things like that. Hope to have made it clear to you what I am after...

PS2: I am NOT asking for changes made to an entity loaded from the database using _dbContext. I am specifically asking for information on changes made to the properties of a newly created entry.

It appears that the _dbContext and EFCore do not pass the initial values of the newly created entry's properties to the OriginalValues!! and I can not figure out why is it so?!?
Wouldn't it be reasonable to have the newly created entry's OriginalValues set to the initial values of the object added to the _dbContext?!? so to giving us the chance of detecting changes to the properties by comparing the original values to the current ones?!?!

Thanx for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can not figure out why is it so?

The ChangeTracker's job to determine what DML statement to run to synchronize the entity with the database.  Tracking the changes made to Added is not necessary to this accomplish this goal, and has a non-zero performance cost.

If you want, you can .Attach the entity if you want EF to track the changes, then change the state to Added before SaveChanges.  But change tracked entities must have a key set, so if the key is database generated you would have to set it to a non-zero value, and reset it to 0 if you change the state to Added.

Comment: David Browne, I did what you suggested. I attached the object to the context. The object has had some initial values. Then I changed lets say the LastName from "AAA" to "BBB". The attached entry's OriginalValues.LastName changed to BBB as well as the CurrentValues.LastName which to me sounds weird!! I would expect the entry's OriginalValues.LastName to keep the initial "AAA" while the entry's CurrentValues.LastName was changed to "BBB". What am I thinking wrong?! Thanx for your time anyway...

Comment: When you attach an entity to the context, wouldn't you expect the entry's OriginalValues to be set to the initial values which the entity has had at the time of the Attach?! And then, when some changes to the values happen afterwards  wouldn't you expect these changes to be reflected to the CurrentValues only and NOT to the OriginalValues as well? Otherwise, what's the point of keeping two copies of the same object within the entry?!?

Comment: You may need to set a non-default key value before attaching, otherwise it will still be in the Added state, not Unchanged.

Comment: Browne thanx a lot. Your last answer helped me a lot.
What was needed was to set the Id to some random integer number. Then, make changes to the properties and finally when I needed to detect if any changes to the properties of the entry were done, either intentionally or by mistake, I used 
var modified = entry.Members.Where(m => m.IsModified).ToList();
and then if the modifications are acceptable then I would change the Id to zero and State to Added and then call the SaveChanges.
Thanx for your help